# ADC timing question. How much time does it need to satisfy timing request?

Tags: fpga, adc

I am trying to read data from an ADC. The timing characteristic is showing as below.

[image: SPI interface of ADC]

[image: Timing request]

The interface is SPI. And the datasheet has told the minimum time of t2 and t3 which refers to SCLK high and low pulse width. But, I don't know the appropriate time width of this two.

Comment: I don't understand the question since the minimum time is written right here in the table and you acknowledged that. There is no maximum time. The time can be as slow as you want.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks.Do you mean that it's ok even if the actual time width is just the same as the minimum time.

Comment: well, that's what it says :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. The datasheet clearly says that (if you have the A or B version) t2 must be at least 60ns and t3 must be at least 30ns. There is no maximum, so you can go as slow as you like, as is normal in SPI.

If you want your system to work as fast as possible, you should design it so t2 is exactly 60ns and t3 is exactly 30ns. That's the fastest the datasheet says you can go.

Yes, if your timing isn't exactly perfect and maybe your "30ns" is actually 29.9ns, that should be okay, even though 29.9 is less than 30, as there is some margin for error. Of course the chip designers don't want that *their* 30ns isn't quite right and the chip needs 30.1ns, so they test their chip at maybe 27-28ns and then write 30ns in the datasheet.

(If you like living dangerously, you could go even faster, see how short the timing can be before the ADC *actually* stops working right. Not working right could be subtle - it could mean the lowest two bits are totally random, for example. It's unlikely to physically hurt the chip - you'll just get incorrect data back, or it will stop responding to commands, or something like that. Occasionally some scientific project or prototype will push limits in this way. I wouldn't recommend it - if you care about reliability at all, stick to what the datasheet says.)

Comment: Good answer. What kind of tolerance (or is the info available) is there typically for timings? For example, if this ADC had a timing tolerance of 10%, and the device reading it had a timing tolerance of 10%, it might be possible to set the device reading it to a timing which looks to be above the required timing, but because of tolerance, is actually under what the ADC device is capable of.

Comment: @LarryBud I think a strict reading says it's your responsibility to make sure the timing is above 30ns, even if that means setting it to 31ns to account for inaccuracy, but a common sense reading says you just aim for 30ns as long as the inaccuracy is a small percentage, which it is, unless your timing source is really bad.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks a ot.I have a question how did you know all about this,since I haven't get this at college or the past company

Comment: @SdrtChapel common sense? I still don't understand how you *didn't* get this from the datasheet. The datasheet is what the chip manufacturer is promising you: the manufacturer says, "use 30ns or more". They are saying it'll be fine if you use 30ns, or 31ns, or 32ns, or 99999999ns.

Comment: There is no tolerance on these numbers.  The datasheet numbers have to be treated as hard limits.  This means that if your design is even 1 ps under the recommended time, the vendor will not guarantee it to work.  It probably will work, but they won't guarantee it.  Best practice is to make sure your design does not violate any datasheet parameters.  This is the first thing they will ask if you want support.  The parameter values in any datasheet are absolute numbers - no tolerance unless explictly stated.   Usually, there is plenty of room to meet the spec on one side or the other.

Comment: @Troutdog when a datasheet says 40MHz do you habitually design for 39.9MHz or do you design for 40MHz? I've never heard anyone say they'd design for 39.9MHz

Comment: @user253751,  If the 40MHz is a maximum frequency, then my first choice would be to run at some lower frequency (say 20MHz).  If max performance is a requirement, then I would figure out the design frequency such that process and tolerance variation would stay below 40MHz.